# Change the color of a specific word in dynamic title

Tags: php, html, css

I have a title in my header that changes depending on the page you're on using this simple PHP code..

```
<?php if(empty($title)) $title = "ASK REAL QUESTIONS, <br>GET FREE ANSWERS.";
echo $title; ?>
```

Here is an example of a page titled "QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS".. The title would say "QUESTIONS.ANSWERS" instead of "ASK REAL QUESTIONS, GET FREE ANSWERS."

```
<?php
$title = "QUESTIONS<br>.ANSWERS";
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/includes/header.php";
include_once($path); ?>
```

and the CSS of $title..

```
    .title {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    font-size: 125%;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #313131;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now here's what I want...

Where it would say "QUESTIONS.ANSWERS".. I want the QUESTIONS to be colored #fff as declared in the CSS... but I want the ".ANSWERS" to be colored #39f.. how can I declare this in PHP?

I tried this... but I get syntax errors.

```
<?php
    $title = "QUESTIONS<br><font color="#39f">.ANSWERS"</font>;
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/includes/header.php";
    include_once($path);  
?>
```

THANKS! :)

Comment: `$title = "QUESTIONS<br><font color=\"#39f\">.ANSWERS</font>";` escaping quotes inside, will get rid of the syntax errors.

Comment: `$title = "QUESTIONS<br><span color=\"#39f\">.ANSWERS"</span>";`

Comment: Sidenote: `<font>` is a deprecated tag. Use `<div>` with a class or id. You're using CSS already.

Comment: Thanks Fred. I'm very very new to HTML, CSS, and PHP. Just started learning about a month ago from sites like Stackoverflow and everywhere else on the web. 

Here's the project I'm currently working on if you're interested! :) www.answers.legal

Comment: You're welcome Michael.

Comment: to answer your question from below is that it conflicts with PHP's wrapping statements tags. Escaping double quotes inside an echo is valid and will render as valid HTML, as per w3.org's standards. Single quotes do work, but aren't considered as valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP can be injected into css. How I would do this is make my .css file a .php instead and preface my css scripts with a `<style>` tag. Then I would, in $title, add a span tag in front of both QUESTIONS and ANSWERS with different id's. Then I would go into my new php file and add conditional statements that dynamically change the color of the text when my conditions are met.

For example:

We place `<span>` tags in front of the two words and give them unique id's. This acts as a specific reference point for css.

```
    <?php
     $title = "<span id='question'>QUESTIONS</span><br>.<span id='answer'>ANSWERS</span>";
     $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
     $path .= "/includes/header.php";
     include_once($path); 
    ?>
```

$path is what changes so we will use that as our condition. (As that is what will change when we want the style to change.

> title in my header that changes depending on the page you're on using

We then change our title.css to titlecss.php. It look like this now.

```
  <style>   //need style tags now that it is .php document
    .title {
      margin: 0 auto;
      color: #fff;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      line-height: 24px;
      padding-top: 12px;
      font-size: 125%;
      position: absolute;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #313131;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
   }

//with the new id's we inject a php tag after `color:` that echoes the new color 
//based on the conditional statement we make (still in `titlecss.php`):

   #question {
     color: <?php 
               if $path === "(whatever $path would be for this style)"{
                  echo "color: #fff;" } 
             ?>
   }
   #answer { }  //same as #question
  </style>
```

Now when `$page` meets our requirements `titlecss.php` will dynamically change the color of the text.

In `header.php` you will need to use an `include` function instead of `<link>` to bring `titlecss.php` to the page.

Comment: Very detailed answer! Thank you Quentin! :) Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code not working because you closed string with " character before it's really ends.

Try this (I changed old deprecated tag "font" to "span" and replaced double quotes to single quote):

```
<?php
    $title = "QUESTIONS<br><span style='color:#39f'>ANSWERS</span>";
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/includes/header.php";
    include_once($path);  
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry! Why can't I use double quotes? :)

Comment: Because you already use the double quotes in your php code. If you want to use double quotes in js - you should to escape " character. Ex :  "QUESTIONS<br><span style=\"color:#39f\">ANSWERS</span>";